# Log file location when application run as ubuntu service. (java, logback)

Tags: ubuntu, service, logback

I have simple aplication written in java that use logback for creating logs. In lockback configuration I have:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logFile.log</file>
    ....
</appender>
```

This work as intended when I simply run application: logFile.log is created in the same location as .jar file. But I want to have also possibility to run this application as service on ubuntu system. I already have .conf file in /etc/init/ directory and it works. I can run application as service and application itself work fine, but logging - not. Log files are saved in / directory. How to change it?

Comment: Check the permission for the user under which you are running the application has write access to the log file

Answer (score 0):

Either hard code the full path:

```
<file>/var/log/logFile.log</file>
```

Or use a system property:

```
<file>${MY_SERVICE_LOG_DIR}/logFile.log</file>
```